# CodeIgniter 2.1.3 - form helper - can't get DATA submitted

Tags: php, codeigniter, formhelper

i am doing a simple form login. After a lot of FAIL tries i downloaded an example in order to understand how it works.
The problem is: After i submit data in my login form and call the controller i can't get the data submitted in controller.

I tried something so simple as print the username and i got nothing.

What i am doing wrong? Should i have to configure something?

Another issue is: When i code the form with normal HTML form, the form works nice.

I used the code that i found here http://www.codefactorycr.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html

I already used another codes, and my own code, but atm i am trying everything in order to understand what is happening.

login_view.php

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
<title>Simple Login with CodeIgniter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Simple Login with CodeIgniter</h1>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
      <br/>
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

verifylogin.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
  }

  function index()
  {

  $username = $this->input->post('username');

  echo "Username: " . $username;
    //This method will have the credentials validation
    $this->load->library('Form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{

  //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
      $this->load->view('login_view');
    }
    else
    {
      //Go to private area
      redirect('home', 'refresh');
    }

  }

  function check_database($password)
  {
    //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
    $username = $this->input->post('username');

    //query the database
    $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

    if($result)
    {
      $sess_array = array();
      foreach($result as $row)
      {
        $sess_array = array(
          'id' => $row->id,
          'username' => $row->username
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
      }
      return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

i can't even write this username

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');

echo "Username: " . $username;
```

Comment: like i said the code is the same of this http://www.codefactorycr.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html But i added what i think is the most important

Answer (score 0):

I also use form helper and its working fine

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('admin/varifylogin'); ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>UserName</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('username',$this->input->post('usernamee'));?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><?php echo form_password('password');?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><?php echo form_submit('login','Sign In');?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Please don't post questions as answers.  Which one is correct answer?

Comment: And you are able to understand or have an idea about my problem?

Comment: Probably the code is correct, you can download the code from this page: http://www.codefactorycr.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html Can maybe the cause of my problem be related with configurations with codeigniter or apache? i don't know, i really don't understand why i can't get data from a form done by form helper